# Facebook App not appearing in bookmark list on left

Tags: facebook

In facebook once you go to an app it automatically appears on the left as a bookmark.  The problem is that the app I have created does not appear in that list automatically.  Does anybody know what the issue is.  I can attach screenshots of all the settings if that will help.

The app is http:// apps.facebook.com/allmodules

This is a test app, the real app will be slightly different but the settings should be the same.

settings

https://i.stack.imgur.com/My9fs.jpg

settings

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx6VO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your application probably burred in end of bookmarks list of the user. And you need to expand the list to see it. As stated in the "Bookmarks for quick re-engagement" section on [Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/):

> These Bookmarks are ordered based on how often and recently the user used your app.